# How do I pose a single mesh?

Tags: rigging

My characters body is one mesh and her head is another. I want to pose her mad make her arms lay down but i can’t do it in edit mode because it messes her whole body up. I was wondering if I could rig her body so i could pose it. if not, how can i pose her?
[image]

Comment: *"...and her head is a mother."* - what does this mean?

Comment: Presumably 'another', i.e; seperate objects.

Comment: You can either rig your mesh, or either you can select your mesh and go into   sculpt mode and use the pose brush, which can kind of automatically rig parts of your mesh and move them.

Comment: I tried the pose in sculpt thing and it messes everything up. I'm a beginner so I probably did everything wrong and it probably would have worked if I did it better